# MS SQL matrix - display column as row and row values as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi have  situation like matrix this out coming with the select query there is a startdate and enddate where condition and I know when start and finish basically is 7day calculation

`T1 = 2 is a sum of 1+1 in same date`

```
SUM(T1) 
WHERE Date BETWEEN 2013/11/11 AND 2013-11-17
```

```
+-----+-------+----+----+----+----+------------+
| ID  | Name  | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 |    Date    |
+-----+-------+----+----+----+----+------------+
| 100 | House |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 | 2013-11-14 |
| 100 | House |  2 |  2 |  2 |  2 | 2013-11-15 |
+-----+-------+----+----+----+----+------------+
```

I need like this

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID  | Type | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 100 | T1   |   00 |   00 |   00 |    2 |    2 |   00 |   00 |
| 100 | T2   |   00 |   00 |   00 |    2 |    2 |   00 |   00 |
| 100 | T3   |   00 |   00 |   00 |    2 |    2 |   00 |   00 |
| 100 | T4   |   00 |   00 |   00 |    2 |    2 |   00 |   00 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I tried to use union all pivot but no idea how complex is this

Genius please help me

Thanks

Hi @conan is working but if i need to add two tables in FROM close like

`FROM #test,test1 WHERE test.Id=test2.Id`

when i do this is saying id is

`Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'pre'.`

`Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 24 The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'Unp'.`

`Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'Final'.`

Comment: I can't formulate one off the top of my head, so will just comment it, use SQL Server's PIVOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#test') is not null drop table #test

create table #test 
    (id int ,name varchar(5),t1 int,t2 int, t3 int ,t4 int,datecol datetime)


insert into #test values (100,'house',2,2,2,2,'20131114');
insert into #test values (100,'house',2,2,2,2,'20131115');
insert into #test values (200,'cabin',1,1,1,1,'20131112');
insert into #test values (200,'cabin',1,1,1,1,'20131113');

select * from #test

DECLARE @startdate AS DATETIME

SET @startdate = '20131111'


SELECT ID
    ,Type
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 1 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day1
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 2 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day2
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 3 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day3
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 4 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day4
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 5 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day5
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 6 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day6
    ,sum(CASE WHEN DaysDiff = 7 THEN holdcolumn ELSE 0 END) AS Day7
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT datediff(d, @startdate, datecol) + 1 DaysDiff
            ,*
        FROM #test
        WHERE datecol BETWEEN @startdate
                AND dateadd(d, 6, @startdate)
        ) AS pre
    unpivot(Holdcolumn FOR [Type] IN (
                t1
                ,t2
                ,t3
                ,t4
                )) AS Unp
    ) AS Final
GROUP BY id
    ,type
ORDER BY id
    ,type
```

Comment: Hi @conan is working but if i need to add two tables in FROM close like `#test,test1 WHERE test.Id=test2.Id` when i do this is saying id is `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'pre'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'Unp'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'Final'.`

Comment: In the "Pre" sub query replace * with column names from your two tables only adding id once. include table name when specifying id so either test.id or test2.id

Comment: Hi, is that possible to add different datatype Type t1,t2,t3,t4 these are integers i need to add t5 that is varchar how can we do that? when i do that is saying `conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.`

Comment: Hi @conan i need to calculate by week so form '01-11-2013' to 30-11-2013 so there is 4 weeks. I tried to change `SELECT datediff(d, @startdate, datecol) + 7 DaysDiff` and case when by 7,14,21,28 but is not giving correct output please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @test  table 
(id int ,name varchar(5),t1 int,t2 int, t3 int ,t4 int,datecol datetime)
insert into @test values (100,'house',2,2,2,2,'20131114');
insert into @test values (100,'house',2,2,2,2,'20131115');
insert into @test values (200,'cabin',1,1,1,1,'20131112');
insert into @test values (200,'cabin',1,1,1,1,'20131113');

Select * from 
(select ID, DName, Orders, Typess
From (select ID, DATENAME(DW, datecol) DName, t1, t2, t3, t4 from @test) a
unpivot(
Orders FOR Typess IN (t1, t2, t3, t4))as unpvot) b
pivot (
sum(Orders) for DName in (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday))as pvot
order by id
```

Comment: Hi, is that possible to add different datatype Type t1,t2,t3,t4 these are integers i need to add t5 that is varchar how can we do that? when i do that is saying conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: Is it sure that there would be single row against each day?

Comment: Can you please let me know the max length of the value.

Comment: Actually the query summarizes the values of types and varchar value can not be summarized so I am looking for a way around. Need some time a little busy.